# s3 interface initialization inside or outside the function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jestjs, aws-sdk

We currently have:

```js
export function s3Call(action: string, params: any): Promise<any> {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  return s3[action](params).promise();
}
```

I tried to change it to:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

export function s3Call(action: string, params: any): Promise<any> {
  return s3[action](params).promise();
}
```

However, when running the unit test, I got the following error:

> failed to get the current sub/segment from the context new s3

[image]

The unit test itself is pretty simple:

```js
describe("uploadImage tests", () => {
  it("should return correct image url", async () => { 
    process.env.IMAGE_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME = 'TestBucket'; 
    process.env.AWS_REGION = 'us-west-2';

    const putObject = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({}));
    AWSMock.mock('S3', 'putObject', putObject);
    const bucketUrl = https://${process.env.IMAGE_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME}.s3-${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/; 

    const result = await uploadImage(imageData, bucketUrl); 

    expect(result).toContain(process.env.IMAGE_UPLOAD_BUCKET_NAME); 
    expect(result).toContain(process.env.AWS_REGION); 

    AWSMock.restore('S3');
  });
});
```

How can the s3 interface be initialized once? and why do we see this error once when s3 initialization is taken out of the function?

Comment: Are you confident that you can use the `s3` object as an array? What are some example values of `action` in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) node package to mock your S3 service.

In the documentation it says,

> The AWS Service needs to be initialised inside the function being tested in order for the SDK method to be mocked

The reason is when you import the file which has `s3Call` inside your test, the s3 service instance is already created (This is not the stub but the actual implementation). Hence, when you call the function, it would use the existing instance instead of the stub you're expecting.